# PostGIS layer and SRS in GeoServer

Tags: qgis, postgis, geoserver, postgresql, layers

I wanted to add layers in GeoServer via my PostGIS database, but I noticed that the native SRS is not recognized and that the declared SRS is EPSG:40400 (see screenshot).

Knowing that I can modify the declared SRS. But there is  a display error. Yet in QGIS I display this same layer through this same database with the SRS that I used in the SRID which is EPSG 3857.

Do you have any suggestions?  [image]

Comment: Can't you set the Native SRS into EPSG:3857 manually?

Comment: how is your table defined?

Comment: No, i can't set Native SRS manually